# how to add a variable to an existing url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite a url from

https://www.example.com

to

https://www.exemple.com?sourcecode

or

https://www.example.com/page1?sourcecode

by adding a variable to the end.

Answer (score 0):

That might be due to other rules in your .htaccess. Use this rule to capture original string from `THE_REQUEST` variable. And add `?` in the end to strip off query string. try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+example(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/page1/%1? [R=301,L,NE]
```